# ¿Cómo solucionar Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pdo() in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Licoreria\index.php:74?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Estoy trantando de incorporar un reporte en pdf, uso dos archivos php, el index y el main donde esta la conexión a la base de datos.

index.php

```
72    require ("./php/main.php");
73    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM producto";
74    $resultado = pdo(conexion(), $consulta);
```

main.php

```
3   # Conexion a la base de datos #
4   function conexion(){
5       $licoreriabd= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=licoreriabd','root','');
6       return $licoreriabd;
7   }
```

Comment: > Call to undefined function pdo() Significa: > Llamada a función sin definir O lo que es lo mismo: No has definido la función previamente en tu código o se te ha olvidado incluir alguna librería/otros que la contiene. Si no me equivoco en php las funciones son case-sensitive o en español, sensibles a las mayúsculas, es decir que en el primer código tienes pdo() y segundo PDO(), lo cuál me resulta extraño, no sé si tendrá que ver con el problema. ¿Podrías mostrarnos el trozo de código donde defines la función "pdo()" o explicar de qué librería la sacas si es que estás importándola?

Comment: Me da el mismo error, la unica vez en la que utilizo PDO en el segundo código para hacer la conexión a la base de datos, nada mas

Answer (score 3):

Si analizas tu código, no existe realmente una función llamada `pdo()`, sino una función llamada `conexion()`, la cual te devuelve una instancia de la clase PDO para interactuar con la base de datos.

Además de eso, el código no está completo, necesitas llamar a los métodos propios de la clase PDO<sup>1</sup> para hacer la consulta SQL, leer los datos, etc. PDO no funciona como el modo procedural de `mysqli`, cuyo modelo pareces seguir en tu código.

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

#### `index.php`

```
require ("./php/main.php");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM producto";
# Aquí $pdo es una instancia de la clase PDO
# que es lo que devuelve la llamada a conexion()
$pdo = conexion();
/*Aquí se consulta y se leen los datos*/
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($consulta);
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    #$row representa cada fila
    var_dump($row);
}
```

#### `main.php`

```
# Conexion a la base de datos #
function conexion(){
    $licoreriabd= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=licoreriabd','root','');
    return $licoreriabd;
}
```

---

#### Notas

1. Si vas a trabajar con PDO, los siguientes enlaces son de obligada lectura:

   - Método [`prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) para consultas preparadas
   - Método [`execute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) para ejecutar consultas preparadas
   - Método [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) para leer los datos